# rank lists in python by their elements

Tags: python, list, rank

I'm trying to do something like a medals tally ranking with Lists in python. I have a List which keeps growing. Each element in the list is a list with four elements.

eg: `L = [[0,1,2,3],[3,0,6,2]]`

I'm trying to rank the elements in this list such that the result turns out to be(for the above eg):

`L = [[3,0,6,2],[0,1,2,3]]` i.e. something like a medals tally where the first element in the inner list is gold, second is silver etc

Is there a simple way to do this in python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the built-in, [sorted](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
sorted(L, reverse=True)
```

[Edit: The above will rank by total number of golds, then number of silvers, etc.  This seems to be the most common way to rank metals (see [Metal Tally here)](http://www.topendsports.com/events/summer/medal-tally/rankings.htm).  You could also define your own function, and use the cmp keyword to rank them a different way.]

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with the sorted link - it doesn't seem to be working - I've tried fixing it 3 times

Comment: I've edited it for you (it'll take a while before it gets peer reviewed, though) - the first line of your post was in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do anything fancy, this is specifically what the built-in `sorted` does.

```
L = [[0,1,2,3],[3,0,6,2],[3,0,5,2],[3,0,6,3],[11,1,0,0],[3,0,7,1]]
sorted(L,reverse=True)

[[11, 1, 0, 0],
 [3, 0, 7, 1],
 [3, 0, 6, 3],
 [3, 0, 6, 2],
 [3, 0, 5, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is a descending sort based on who has the most medals, you could use:

```
L = [[0,1,2,3],[3,0,6,2],[0,0,0,22]]
sorted(L, key=sum, reverse=True)
```

Specifying `sum` as the key causes sorted to call the function on each element to compute the key value.

Comment: Or instead of `sum` he could use his own ranking function, e.g. `medal_tally_rank = lambda L: L[0]*4+L[1]*2+L[2]*1+L[3]*0.5` and then execute `sorted(L, key=medal_tally_rank, ...)`.

Comment: Why `4`, `2`, `1` and `0.5` ? Isn't the medal ranking only based on gold, then if tied on silver, etc ?

Comment: They were just random numbers, they don't mean anything, but I did though that if he's storing 4 numbers, all of them must have some value, even if tiny. There are also different ranking systems. For example the British press used 5:3:1, someone from Australia used 3:2:1 while an article from NY Times mentioned 4:2:1.